# Turn by turn navigation with coordinates of each route step end points

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mapkit

I am using Apple Mapkit inside an app to show turn by turn navigation given start and end coordinates. And I have used (void)calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:(MKDirectionsHandler)completionHandler for this purpose. It returns distance (549m, 100m, etc.) and instructions (Turn left, Proceed, etc.).

Is it possible to get the coordinates of each route step's start and end points? For example, if I want to get from point A to B, is it possible to get the coordinates of all the intermediate turning points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible by reading first and last point in the `MKPolyLine` object for a step ... like this:

```
// start coordinate of step1
CLLocationCoordinate2D startCoordinate;
[step1.polyline getCoordinates:&startCoordinate range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];

// end coordinate of step1
CLLocationCoordinate2D endCoordinate;
[step1.polyline getCoordinates:&endCoordinate range:NSMakeRange(step1.polyline.pointCount - 1, 1)];
```